# How to fetch already created .db and use it on Android Studio?

Tags: android, database, android-studio

I've a HOSPITALS.db file in my assets folder. I want to access the data from the DB. I already have a code for accessing the data inside the table, I want to access the .db file itself so it won't produce an error not finding the table.

```
protected void openDatabase() {
    db = openOrCreateDatabase("HOSPITALS", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Get Your Database path using the following

```
ContextWrapper cw =new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());
DB_PATH =cw.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath()+ "/databases/"; //edited to databases
```

Then you can go this way

```
private void copyDataBase()
    {
        Log.i("Database",
                "New database is being copied to device!");
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        OutputStream myOutput = null;
        int length;
        // Open your local db as the input stream
        InputStream myInput = null;
        try
        {
            myInput =myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
            // transfer bytes from the inputfile to the
            // outputfile
            myOutput =new FileOutputStream(DB_PATH+ DB_NAME);
            while((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0)
            {
                myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
            myOutput.close();
            myOutput.flush();
            myInput.close();
            Log.i("Database",
                    "New database has been copied to device!");


        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: it produces an error `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference`

Comment: I changed the DB_NAME into HOSPITALS since the filename is HOSPITALS.db

Comment: at first it's this line `ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());` then i changed it to `this`. It worked. Now this line errors, `String DB_PATH = cw.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath()+ "/databases/"`

Comment: change "DB_NAME" to  "HOSPITALS.db"

Comment: try this full tutorial that will explain how to copy existing db file from assets folder http://www.androprogrammer.com/2014/08/create-or-copy-database-in-android.html

Comment: it is still the same

Comment: try this links hope it will helpfull https://gist.github.com/donaldlittlepie/1271795    http://iamvijayakumar.blogspot.in/2013/11/copy-sqlite-database-file-from-assets.html

Comment: i tried it. It still does not work. It throws an error of no such table. I dont have to add `_id` right since i dont have a column of that